# Combining numpy with sympy

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I have a the following code:

```
p = classp();
for i in range(1,10):
   x = numpy.array([[2],[4],[5]])
   print p.update(x)

class classp:
   def __init__(self):
       self.mymodel = array([2*x[1]], [3*x[0]], [x[2]]);
   def update(self, x):
       return self.mymodel #replace x(0)...x(1) with the given parameter
```

My question is related the code above, I would like to define a model using sympy if it's possible, afterwards in the update function replace the sympy variables with the x values. Is it possible? How can I do that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I can propose you two solutions.

Firstly, there is `DeferedVector` that was created for use with `lambdify`:

```
In [1]: from sympy.matrices import DeferredVector

In [2]: v = DeferredVector('v')

In [3]: func = lambdify(v, Matrix([v[1], 2*v[2]]))

In [4]: func(np.array([10,20,30]))
Out[4]: 
       [[20] 
        [60]]
```

However lambdify does too much magic for my taste.

Another option is to use the `.subs` method:

```
In [11]: x1, x2, x3 = symbols('x1:4')

In [12]: m = Matrix([x2,2*x1,x3/2])

In [13]: m.subs({x1:10, x2:20, x3:30})
Out[13]: 
        ⎡20⎤
        ⎢  ⎥
        ⎢20⎥
        ⎢  ⎥
        ⎣15⎦
```

You can create the dictionary for the substitution like that:

`dict(zip(symbols('x1:4'), your_value_array))`.

Do not forget that all the return objects are sympy matrices. To convert them to numpy arrays just use `np.array(the_matrix_in_question)` and do not forget to specify the `dtype`, otherwise it will default to `dtype=object`.

Comment: @TobiasKienzler, actually I strongly dislike `lambdify` in its current state. It is a convoluted and unpredictable function that does not even have a well defined scope of applications. Sometimes it even returns symbolic objects when the whole point was to be used for numerical evaluations.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate :-( I haven't used it that much so far, but the idea behind it sounds really great....

Comment: It is good enough for simple interactive work, but for instance it was completely reimplemented for the plotting module (but due to differences and all the inherited bizarreness the new version is not exposed in the global namespace yet). There are also other options like code generation and automatic compilation with C, Fortran and Theano if you are interested.