# Incompatability when upgrading Scipy cannot use SciPy function on SymPy matrix

Tags: numpy, sympy

I have recently upgraded my SciPy stack. Ipython Notebooks that previously worked now fail in the new Jupyter Notebook.

Previously I could evaluate SymPy matrices using SciPy/NumPy functions. Below is a minimal example with the `eig` function from SciPy performed on a SymPy matrix. It returns `object arrays are not supported`. This did not used to happen. During my upgrade several packages may have upgraded, including SymPy.
[image: Jupyter Notebook Screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how it worked in your previous setup, but the process of converting SymPy matrices to NumPy arrays was explicit as early as 2012, per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10138307), and SymPy has a utility function [`matrix2numpy`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html#numpy-utility-functions-reference) for this purpose. So, in your context

```
LA.eig(matrix2numpy(M, dtype=float))
```

returns the expected eigenvalues. Without the helper function, it could be

```
LA.eig(np.array(M.tolist(), dtype=float))
```

If you'd like SciPy functions to accept SymPy objects, that would be an issue for [their tracker](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues), rather than a question for Stack Overflow.

Comment: I must have had a very old version of SymPy or NumPy beforehand.