# Python-How to multiply matrix with symbols and 0s

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am brand new to python, but is there any way to multiply matrices with both 0's and symbols? For example, see below:

```
import sympy as sym
import numpy as np
teams=np.matrix([[1,2],[3,4]])
teams=teams-1
n=4
x,a,b=sym.symbols('x a b')
X=np.empty((n,n), dtype=object)
Y=np.empty((n,n), dtype=object)
Z=np.empty((n,n), dtype=object)
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
            if j==i:
                X[i,j]=x
            elif ([i,j] in teams.tolist()):
                Y[i,j]=a
            elif ([j,i] in teams.tolist()):
                Y[i,j]=a
            else:
                Z[i,j]=b
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if X[i,j]==None:
            X[i,j]=0
        if Y[i,j]==None:
            Y[i,j]=0
        if Z[i,j]==None:
            Z[i,j]=0

print(np.matmul(X,Y))

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-189-00b753462a2d> in <module>
      2 print(Y)
      3 print(Z)
----> 4 print(np.matmul(X,Y))

TypeError: ufunc 'matmul' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

I know why it is messing up, I am trying to multiply a symbol by a number, but I was wondering if there was anyway to make this recognize that a symbol times 0 is just zero and should be disregarded if being added to another symbol.

Comment: The basic problem is that numpy can not handle sympy symbols. Whenever you have symbols, everything needs to stay inside sympy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested your code with `print(np.dot(X,Y))` instead of `print(np.matmul(X,Y))` and it worked. According to the documentation `np.matmul` is preferred over `np.dot` for matrix multiplication, but I wasn't able to figure out how to do it using `np.matmul`. I tried `np.matmul(X, Y, casting='unsafe')`, but the same error resulted. I don't think the error is caused by adding 0 or multiplying by 0, sympy is able to do simplifications.

E.g.

```
x = sym.symbols('x')
print(x + 0)
print(x*0)
print(3*x + 5*x)
```

returns just as expected x, 0 and x*8.

Hopefully this helps you out.

Answer (score 3):

Whenever you are working with symbolic math, you should leave out numpy and keep everything inside sympy. Numpy doesn't understand about sympy's symbols. You can be lucky a few times with multiplying by zero, but it doesn't make much sense in general. Numpy works with arrays of numbers, preferably everything of the same type.

However, you *can* use [lambdify](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/utilities/lambdify.html) to bridge the gap and [convert sympy expressions to be used by numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10129213/combining-numpy-with-sympy).

Here is your code with [sympy's matrices](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/common.html):

```py
import sympy as sym

teams = sym.Matrix([[1, 2], [3, 4]])
teams = teams - sym.ones(2, 2)

n = 4
x, a, b = sym.symbols('x a b')
X = sym.zeros(n, n)
Y = sym.zeros(n, n)
Z = sym.zeros(n, n)

for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if j == i:
            X[i, j] = x
        elif [i, j] in teams.tolist() or [j, i] in teams.tolist():
            Y[i, j] = a
        else:
            Z[i, j] = b
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(n):
        if X[i, j] is None:
            X[i, j] = 0
        if Y[i, j] is None:
            Y[i, j] = 0
        if Z[i, j] is None:
            Z[i, j] = 0
print(X * Y)
```

Result:

```py
Matrix([[0, a*x, 0, 0],
        [a*x, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, a*x],
        [0, 0, a*x, 0]])
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem isn't specifically with the `symbols`, but with the object dtype.  `matmul` doesn't (or didn't) work with object dtype arrays. The fast version uses `BLAS` library functions, which only work with C numeric types - float and integers.  `np.dot` does have a slower branch that does work with non-numeric dtypes.

In a `isympy` session:

```
In [4]: X                                                                       
Out[4]: 
array([[x, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, x, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, x, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, x]], dtype=object)

In [5]: Y                                                                       
Out[5]: 
array([[0, a, 0, 0],
       [a, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, a],
       [0, 0, a, 0]], dtype=object)

In [6]: np.dot(X,Y)                                                             
Out[6]: 
array([[0, a*x, 0, 0],
       [a*x, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, a*x],
       [0, 0, a*x, 0]], dtype=object)
```

BUT, `matmul` does work for me.  I wonder if that's because of my numpy version?

```
In [7]: np.matmul(X,Y)                                                          
Out[7]: 
array([[0, a*x, 0, 0],
       [a*x, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, a*x],
       [0, 0, a*x, 0]], dtype=object)

In [8]: np.__version__                                                          
Out[8]: '1.17.4'
```

As a general rule mixing `sympy` and `numpy` is not a good idea.  `numpy` arrays containing `symbols` are necessarily object dtype.  Math on object dtype depends on delegating the action to methods.  The result is hit-or-miss.  Multiplication and addition may work (`x+x`), but `np.sin` does not, because `x.sin()` fails.  It's best to use `sympy.lambdify` if you want to use `sympy` expressions in `numpy`.  Otherwise, try to use pure `sympy`.

```
In [12]: X*X                                                                    
Out[12]: 
array([[x**2, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, x**2, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, x**2, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, x**2]], dtype=object)

In [13]: np.sin(X)                                                              
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
AttributeError: 'Symbol' object has no attribute 'sin'
```

===

From the numpy 1.17.0 release notes

```
Support of object arrays in matmul¶
It is now possible to use matmul (or the @ operator) with object arrays. For instance, it is now possible to do:

from fractions import Fraction
a = np.array([[Fraction(1, 2), Fraction(1, 3)], [Fraction(1, 3), Fraction(1, 2)]])
b = a @ a
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing out that it is possible to multiply matrices with @